# RecordRTC crash after 1 minute of recording

Tags: javascript, html, ffmpeg, webrtc

I am using RecordRTC to record a webcam stream and using ffmpeg to convert the output into .mp4 recording of 1min video is fine and the browser merge both the audio and video into a single .mp4 however recording that is longer than 1min will encounter this error.

i had also asked the author of [RecordRTC](https://www.webrtc-experiment.com/ffmpeg/merging-wav-and-webm-into-mp4.html) and he mentioned something about buffersize which i had changed to 0 and still encounter the same problem.

[image: error]

My Sample Code

```
var audioRecorder, videoRecorder, videoURL, connectionStream;
    function initRecorders(stream) {
        //document.getElementById('start-recording').disabled = false;
        document.getElementById('stop-recording').disabled = false;
        document.getElementById('fullscreeniframe').disabled = false;
        //document.getElementById('save-video').disabled = false;
        //document.getElementById('start-recording').onclick = function() {
            this.disabled = true;
            audioRecorder = RecordRTC(stream, {
                recorderType: StereoAudioRecorder,
                bufferSize: 0,  // mandatory: if 720p output is forced. otherwise: optional
                width: 1280, // optional---- to get 720p output
                height: 720
            });

            videoRecorder = RecordRTC(stream, {
                type: 'video', 
                frameInterval: 90
            });

            videoRecorder.initRecorder(function() {
                audioRecorder.initRecorder(function() {
                    audioRecorder.startRecording();
                    videoRecorder.startRecording();
                });
            });
        //};``
```

i also changed the value inside RecordRTC.js

```
 // "0" means, let chrome decide the most accurate buffer-size for current platform.
    var bufferSize = typeof config.bufferSize === 'undefined' ? 0: config.bufferSize;

    if (legalBufferValues.indexOf(bufferSize) === -1) {
        if (!config.disableLogs) {
            console.warn('Legal values for buffer-size are ' + JSON.stringify(legalBufferValues, null, '\t'));
        }
    }
```

Update: RecordRTC developer have replied

1) take all code from this repo: https://github.com/bgrins/videoconverter.js/

2) Set maximum possible value for memory-size

3) Set maximum possible values for array-buffer and other things

4) compile to "videoconveter.js" and "videoconvter.min.js"

5) use compiled file with RecordRTC

I had download the source code but am unsure how to set maximum value for memory/array-buffer and others.
how do i use the file with RecordRTC too?